# Is there any way to add two things to a list at the same time instead of double appending-python

Tags: python

I have recently starting coding and so far I only have about a month and a half of experience so I'm still learning. I am taking a stab at object oriented programming but I am trying to see where I can improve my code. For the purpose of this question, specifically the last method of code. As you can see in my where_to_watch_movie method, I have an instance in which I use append twice. I have read that repeating your code twice is a bad practice, so I am wondering if there is any other way to add these items to the list. I cannot use extend, but if there is no alternative way, I can also keep my double append as there will be no penalty for repeating myself. Still would like to know for my own best practices moving forward though if anyone knows!

```
class Movie:
    """Movie class that takes four data members"""
    def __init__(self, title, genre, director, year):
        self.title = title
        self.genre = genre
        self.director = director
        self.year = year

    def get_title(self):
        """get title of the movie"""
        return self.title

    def get_genre(self):
        """get genre of the move"""
        return self.genre

    def get_director(self):
        """"get director of the movie"""
        return self.director

    def get_year(self):
        """"get year of the movie"""
        return self.year


'''class StreamingService:
    def __init__(self, name):
        """streaming service class that takes two data members. THe catalog is a dictionary of movies with the titles
        as keys and the movie objects as the corresponding values."""
        self.name = name
        self.catalog = dict()

    def get_name(self):
        """returns name of the streaming service"""
        return self.name

    def get_catalog(self):
        """returns the catalog"""
        return self.catalog

    def add_movie(self, mov):
        """add movie to the catalog"""
        self.catalog[mov.get_title()] = mov

    def delete_movie(self, title):
        """delete movie from the catalog"""
        if title in self.catalog:
            self.catalog.pop(title)


class StreamingGuide:
    def __init__(self):
        """streaming guide"""
        self.StreamingServices = []

    def add_streaming_service(self, streamingservice):
        """add streaming service to the streaming services list"""
        self.StreamingServices.append(streamingservice)

    def delete_streaming_service(self, streamingservicename):
        """remove streaming service from the streaming services list"""
        if streamingservicename in self.StreamingServices:
            self.StreamingServices.remove(streamingservicename)

    def where_to_watch_movie(self, title):
        """returns a list that contains the name of the movie and year, as well as the streaming service
        where you can find that movie."""
        list_1 = []
        for item in self.StreamingServices:
            if title in item.get_catalog():
                list_1.append(item.get_catalog()[title].get_title() + " ("
                                + str(item.get_catalog()[title].get_year()) + ")")
                list_1.append(item.get_name())
            if len(list_1) == 0:
                return None
            else:
                return list_1


"""
movie_1 = Movie('The Seventh Seal', 'comedy', 'Ingmar Bergman', 1957)
movie_2 = Movie('Home Alone', 'tragedy', 'Chris Columbus', 1990)
movie_3 = Movie('Little Women', 'action thriller', 'Greta Gerwig', 2019)
movie_4 = Movie('Galaxy Quest', 'historical documents', 'Dean Parisot', 1999)


stream_serv_1 = StreamingService('Netflick')
stream_serv_1.add_movie(movie_2)

stream_serv_2 = StreamingService('Hula')
stream_serv_2.add_movie(movie_1)
stream_serv_2.add_movie(movie_4)
stream_serv_2.delete_movie('The Seventh Seal')
stream_serv_2.add_movie(movie_2)

stream_serv_3 = StreamingService('Dizzy+')
stream_serv_3.add_movie(movie_4)
stream_serv_3.add_movie(movie_3)
stream_serv_3.add_movie(movie_1)

stream_guide = StreamingGuide()
stream_guide.add_streaming_service(stream_serv_1)
stream_guide.add_streaming_service(stream_serv_2)
stream_guide.add_streaming_service(stream_serv_3)
stream_guide.delete_streaming_service('Hula')
search_results = stream_guide.where_to_watch_movie('Little Women')"""
```

Comment: You can use `.extend()` with a tuple or list of values.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).